# How can I convert an array of strings to an array of integers?

Tags: php, sql, int, apple-push-notifications

I'm getting this error with my current PHP code:

> Notice: TO id was not an integer: 1, 2. 1) APNS::queueMessage ->

How can I convert to an array of strings to an array of integers like in this other question: [ID not integer... EasyAPNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350620/id-not-integer-easyapns) ?

I'm basically trying to pass `id`s (from my database,) to `newMessage()` like this Apple example:

```
// SEND MESSAGE TO MORE THAN ONE USER
// $apns->newMessage(array(1,3,4,5,8,15,16)); 
// ($destination contain a string with the Ids like "1,2,3")
```

Here is my code below:

```
if (isset($destination))
{
    //$destination = 1,2,.. 
    $dest = explode(",", $destination);
    if (isset($time))
    {
        $apns->newMessage($dest, $time);
    }
    else
    {
        $apns->newMessage($dest);
    }

    $apns->addMessageAlert($message);
    $apns->addMessageBadge($badge);
    $apns->addMessageSound('bingbong.aiff');
    $apns->queueMessage();
    header("location:$url/index.php?success=1");
}
```

Comment: What? I don't get it, what's the question? What's the problem?

Comment: Looks like `$apns->queueMessage()` expects an integer parameter. But with that little information it's only guesswork

Comment: And what's your actual variable set to (include that line) and include what line the error is on pls.

Comment: If you just want to print out the contents of the array you can call either serialize, or implode with some glue characters... not sure if that is what you want though

Comment: What I'm looking for is to pass ids to newMessage like this Apple example: // SEND MESSAGE TO MORE THAN ONE USER
//$apns->newMessage(array(1,3,4,5,8,15,16)); $destination contain a string with the Ids like "1,2,3"

Comment: I took a shot at answering your question, in my answer below.  Basically, I believe your error ended up coming from the fact that you needed to have your string `id` values converted to ints before being used in the `$apns->newMessage()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a wrapper function that accepts an array, and then call it.

```
function newMessageArray($array) {
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        $apns->newMessage($element);
    }
}
```

This way, you can call `newMessageArray()` with an array of integers, such as `array(1,2,3,4,5)`, and they will all be sent.

Also, you should change the variable names (from `$array` and `$element`) to something more meaningful.  I don't know what you're trying to do, so I wasn't sure what names to use.

Comment: Thank You so much it WORKS! I'm starting to learn php so it was so unclear what was my problem but you fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: If it works for you, great!  But... isn't the point of your problem that you had an array of `strings` that needed to become `int`s?  According to the `apns` doc comments, the $apns->newMessage() already takes an array.  It's just that you had an array of strings... instead of ints... right?

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear, It's only a guess work. 
It seems to be error in convert integer, try

```
$dest = explode(",", $destination);
$destArray = array();
foreach($dest as $key => $val) {
  $destArray[$key] = intval($val);
}

if (isset($time))
{
    $apns->newMessage($destArray, $time);
}
else
{
    $apns->newMessage($destArray);
}
```

Convert where the string is not integer using 'intval'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you may be looking for is how to do this:

You have `id`s in your database table, right?  And you are trying to get multiple `id`s into an array so that the array can be used in `$apns->newMessage()` call, right?  (I checked [the source](https://github.com/manifestinteractive/easyapns/blob/master/src/php/classes/class_APNS.php) for this...)  But, the `id`s are somehow coming over as `string`s instead of `int`s.

So, you probably want to just make sure that the new array is made up of `int`s, like this:

```
function to_int($x) {
    return (int)$x;
}

$dest = array_map("to_int", $dest);
```

There are probably other ways to do this, but this way, you at least know that you have int variables in that array.  Hope that helps!